# jQuery Autocomplete plugin issue

Tags: jquery, plugins, autocomplete

I have a requirement in my project to provide an autocomplete feature for a textBox like the one recently applied on Google. I need to fetch data on each keystroke so I am calling a jQuery function on keypress. The problem is the Autocomplete feature gets triggered on mouse click in the textBox and not on keypress. I will attach the code snippet for a better understanding of the problem which goes like this

```
$(document).keypress(function(){ 
    lastKey = String.fromCharCode(window.event.keyCode); 
    alert('lastKey :: ' + lastKey);
    var txtVal = document.frm.selectedTechParamName.value + lastKey; 
    alert('txtVal :: ' + txtVal); 
    $("#suggestTechParamName").autocomplete('/AEA-Authoring/TechnicianParameterAutocomplete?userAction=getTechParamsForSvcLvlDataID&txtVal=' + txtVal, { 
        matchContains: true, 
        minChars: 0, 
        cacheLength:0, 
        maxItemsToShow:10
    }); 
});
```

Now what's going on is when any key is pressed the alerts are working properly, but the second half of the function i.e.

```
$("#suggestTechParamName").autocomplete('/AEA-Authoring/TechnicianParameterAutocomplete?userAction=getTechParamsForSvcLvlDataID&txtVal=' + txtVal, { 
    matchContains: true, 
    minChars: 0, 
    cacheLength:0, 
    maxItemsToShow:10
});
```

gets called when we click on the textBox. Also as you can see the attribute "cacheLength:0" which I have written is because I do not want Autocomplete to cache any data, but this also does not seem working.

Comment: Hi - could you edit you question to mark your code as code so it's less headachy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this and the things worked just fine for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#suggestTechParamName").autocomplete('/AEA-Authoring/TechnicianParameterAutocomplete', {
        extraParams: { userAction: 'getTechParamsForSvcLvlDataID'
                     }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using the [JQuery plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) to achieve this. I use the same plugin and every time a key is pressed it sends a new Ajax request to the server.

You mentioned that you are setting `cacheLength` to `0`, according to the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions), the value must be `>= 1`. Have you tried changing this to see if it changes the behaviour?

**Edit 1:** Also, according to the docs, it appears that `matchContains: true` is only useful if you have `cacheLength > 1` (`cacheLength = 1` means no caching, default is `cacheLength = 10`).

Answer (score 1):

Try unbinding the click event from the textbox you have attached your autocompleter to:

```
$( "#suggestTechParamName").autocomplete('/AEA-Authoring/TechnicianParameterAutocomplete?userAction=getTechParamsForSvcLvlDataID&txtVal=' + txtVal, {
    matchContains: true,
    minChars: 0, cacheLength:0, maxItemsToShow:10
}).unbind("click");
```

Comment: Hi !
When I tried to unbind the click event, the stuff stopped working at all.
Any suggestions ?